# Does this symbol 术 has any meaning of its own?

Tags: kanji

This symbol 术 is part of several kanjis. Does it have a meaning of its own? I looked for it in kanji lists and a japanese dictionary and it doesnt list any meaning

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does have a meaning of its own, but it is better represented by「朮」instead.「术」is a handwritten style of the character forced into [Minchōtai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_(typefaces)) fonts, and you can somewhat think of「术」vs.「朮」as Shinjitai vs. Kyūjitai (although this way of viewing it has some limitations).

---

「朮」originally depicted a [Sorghum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorghum_bicolor) plant (Chinese: 高梁, Japanese: モロコシ) which is the original meaning with the historical form:

[image]

This meaning is now written as「秫」.「[朮]{じゅつ}」is used as a phonetic component in the Jōyō kanji「述」and「術」(pending on the font you're using it may look like「术」instead).

---

The other place where it's found is in the bottom-left hand side of Kyūjitai 「{{zh-TW:殺}}」(compare Shinjitai「殺」, where the dot is missing). Here,「朮」serves as a graphically corrupted semantic component, originally representing a person who was about to get their head chopped off.

[image]

*Change over time in the component depicting a person due to be executed in the character*「{{zh-TW:殺}}」, *eventually transforming into*「朮」.

「朮」does not provide sound or meaning here, because it was originally something else.

---

Lastly, in Simplified Chinese,「术」is the official form of「術」.

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)